# Set-MailboxFolderPermission does not, what it should do

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm currently working on a script to change some Mailboxfolderpermissions in Exchange 2010. 
The basic functions work, I can read out the current permission-status and I can set permissions, but the cmdlet Set-Mailboxfolderpermission does not correctly set the permissions.

For example:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity Owner:\Calendar -User TargetUser -AccessRights Contributor
```

This results in a custom named setting, where nothing changed in relation to the previous setting.
Same thing when I substitute `Contributor` with the explicit permissions `FolderVisible, CreateItems`.

**Update:**

I just tried to use the cmdlet from the shell and there it works.
To test whether the internal output is right, I printed the permissions on the shell and everything was fine. 
Right now I'm wondering even more.

What is the point here? Is it a bug, am I to frustrated to see the right way out of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I use the below - just be certain to use the UPN & Set permission  - Set doesn't always work - You could just  first remove the current &  then add a different permission:

```
Remove-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "Owner@something.com:\calendar" -User targetUser@something.com 

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "Owner@something.com:\calendar" -User targetUser@something.com -AccessRights owner
```

Comment: Thanks for the guess, I'm going to test it asap!

Comment: SET-* edits an existing ACL entry.  Add-* is necessary to create a new ACL.